# Sources of Flash Player 10 context menu item handlers?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Where can I get sources of Flash Player 10 context menu "print" handler?

Comment: ...are you asking for the source of the Adobe Flash runtime?

Comment: Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin

Comment: I need to realize the functionality that I have in browser by clicking mouse right button on Flash movie and choose "print".

Comment: You have to realize there is no print function by default you have to make it.

Comment: google? ist hit for as3 print: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422259/as3-using-printjob-to-print-a-movieclip