# Trouble with MouseEvent when using printJob

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a presentation in AS3 and AIR and need to be able to print individual slides (maybe eventually, multiple slides). I'm not a programmer at all. I've done a bit with AS2 in the past and now I'm starting over with AS3.

I started with this code:

```
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,printContent);

function printContent(evt:MouseEvent) {
   var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

   if (printJob.start()) {

      if (content_mc.width>printJob.pageWidth) {
         content_mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
         content_mc.scaleY=content_mc.scaleX;
      }

      printJob.addPage(content_mc);
      printJob.send();
   }
}
```

This works, but is a bit dysfunctional, doesn't reset the clip, etc., etc.

I then tried the final code posted here: [AS3 using PrintJob to print a MovieClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422259/as3-using-printjob-to-print-a-movieclip)

Just dropping this into the timeline and changing a couple of things worked much better. At least as far as launching the print dialogue, resizing, printing, "reseting the clip", etc. The only thing missing is a bit better placement on the printed page …and I'm having a problem getting a Mouse Event work properly. I tried setting it up as close as I could to the code in this post, something like this:

```
printSlide12_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, printMovieClip);
}

function printMovieClip(clip:MovieClip):void {
```

But haven't been able to get this or anything else to work. I know I'm probably just doing something completely wrong here, but can't seem to find an example that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't mentioning exactly what has gone wrong, but what I can see is that your handler is incorrect try this :

```
function printMovieClip(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   // put your print code here
}
```

Your event handler should accept a MouseEvent, as that is what the listener is listening for.

"And I'm having a problem getting a Mouse Event work properly" is rather vague, so including an error is helpful and the line that is causing the error at minimum.